# I got different outputs on run and debug in C

Tags: c, debugging, memory, memory-management, output

My code will take the info from input.txt that students informations. hold them in a linked list and then sort them by birth year then print. when ı run, it print meanless numbers and every time ı run, the output changes. but when ı debug code, the output will be correct.

When ı run my code the output:
Student names in ascending order by birthday:
-2013265920000
M-2013265920-2013265920-2013265920-2013265920
Ali Pehlivan;2005
-2013265920-2013265920-20132659200

But I debug my code and output:
Student names in ascending order by birthday:
Ali Pehlivan;2005
Selami Kilic;2002
Esma Sultan;2001
Mehmet Ali Sarsil;2000

my input file 'input.txt' as:
040160811;Ali Pehlivan;2005
040180224;Mehmet Ali Sarsil;2000
820190040;Esma Sultan;2001
150190207;Selami Kilic;2002

it seems about my 'sortAndPrintByBirth' function. But ı cannot find any mistake.
I think its a memory stuff.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct n {
    char number[9];
    char name;
    int year;
    struct n* next;
};
typedef struct n node;


struct s_node {
    char* number;
    struct s_node *next;
}*stack = NULL;





int isLetter(char character);
int isNumber(char character);
int charToInt(char character);
node** sortAndPrintByBirth(node* *list);
node** sortAndPrintByFaculty(node* *list);
int length(node** list);
void push(char* value);
char* pop();
void display();

        int main() {

    node* Student;
    Student = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* head1;
    node* head;
    head = Student;
    head1 = head;
    node* Students[100];

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\PC\\CLionProjects\\untitled1\\input.txt", "r");
    char fchar;
    fchar = fgetc(file);
    int switchNY = 0; // 0 for school number, 1 for birth year
    int studentCounter = 0;
    while(fchar != EOF){               /// Dosyadan veri alma
        if(isLetter(fchar)){
            head1->name = fchar;
            head1->year = (int) NULL;
            head1->next = malloc(sizeof(node*));
            head1 = head1->next;
            fchar = fgetc(file);
        }else if(isNumber(fchar)){
            if(switchNY == 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                    head1->number[i] = fchar;
                    head1->year =(int) NULL;
                    head1->number[i+1] = (char) NULL;
                    fchar = fgetc(file);
                }

            }else {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    head1->year = charToInt(fchar);
                    head1->next = malloc(sizeof(node *));
                    head1 = head1->next;
                    fchar = fgetc(file);
                }
                if (fchar == EOF) {
                    Students[studentCounter] = head;         ///en son yapmaya çalıştığın şey her \n karakterinde
                    Students[studentCounter + 1] = NULL;     ///yeni student tanımlayıp onun adresini arrayde tutmak
                    fchar = fgetc(file);
                    Student = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
                    head = Student;
                    head1 = head;
                    studentCounter++;
                }
                switchNY = 0;
            }

        }else if(fchar == '\n'){                         /// kod ; lerde buraya giriyo, onu düzelt
            Students[studentCounter] = head;             ///en son yapmaya çalıştığın şey her \n karakterinde
            Students[studentCounter+1] = NULL;           ///yeni student tanımlayıp onun adresini arrayde tutmak
            fchar = fgetc(file);
            Student = (node *)  malloc(sizeof(node));
            head = Student;
            head1 = head;
            studentCounter++;
        }else if(fchar == ';'){
            head1->year = (int) NULL;
            if(switchNY == 1){
                head1->name = fchar;
            }
            switchNY = 1;
            fchar = fgetc(file);
            head1->next = malloc(sizeof(node*));
            head1 = head1->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);


    sortAndPrintByBirth(Students);
    //sortAndPrintByFaculty(Students);


    return -1;
}


int isLetter(char character) {
    return ((character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') || (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') || (character == ' '));
}
int isNumber(char character) {
    return (character >= '0' && character <= '9');
}
int charToInt(char character) {
    if (character >= '0' && character <= '9') {
        return character - '0';
    } else {
        return -1; // Eğer karakter bir sayı değilse -1 döndür
    }
}


node** sortAndPrintByBirth(node* *list) {
    int i = length(list);
    node* result[i];

    for(int a=0; a<i; a++){
        result[a] = list[a]->number;
    }



    for(int count = 0; count < i-1; count++){
        for(int step = 0; step < i-1 ; step++){
            node *iter1;
            node *iter2;
            iter1 = result[step];
            iter2 = result[step+1];
            int year1 = 0,year2 = 0;
            while (iter2 != NULL){
                while ((void *) iter1->next->year == NULL) { ///void* eklendi, derleyicinin isteği
                    iter1 = iter1->next;
                }
                while ((void *) iter2->next->year == NULL) { ///void* eklendi, derleyicinin isteği
                    iter2 = iter2->next;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                    iter1 = iter1->next;
                    year1 = 10 * year1 + iter1->year;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                    iter2 = iter2->next;
                    year2 = 10 * year2 + iter2->year;
                }
                break;
            }
            if(year1 < year2){
                node* temp;
                temp = result[step];
                result[step] = result[step+1];
                result[step+1] = temp;
            }else if(year2 == year1){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    node* iter3;
    printf("Student names in ascending order by birthday:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        iter3 = result[j]->next;
        while(iter3->year == (int )NULL){
            printf("%c",iter3->name);
            iter3 = iter3->next;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
            printf("%d",iter3->year);
            iter3 = iter3->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return result;
}


node** sortAndPrintByFaculty(node* *list){
    int i = length(list);
    node* result[i];
    char* temp[i];

    for(int a=0; a<i; a++){
        temp[a] = list[a]->number;
    }

    /// temp  = "040160811","040180224","820190040","150190207"

    for(int count = 0; count < i-1; count++){
        for(int step = 0; step < i-1 ; step++){
            for(int digit = 0; digit < 3 ; digit ++){
                if(charToInt(temp[step][digit]) < charToInt(temp[step+1][digit])){
                    char* c;
                    c = temp[step];
                    temp[step] = temp[step+1];
                    temp[step+1] = c;
                    break;
                }else if(charToInt(temp[step][digit]) == charToInt(temp[step+1][digit])){
                    continue;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        push(temp[j]);              ///Değerler büyükten küçüğe stack'e push'landı.
    }
    //display();
    printf("School numbers by the faculty codes in ascending order:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        printf("%s\n", pop());
    }

    return result;
}

int length(node** list){
    int value = 0;
    while(list[value] != NULL){
        value++;
    }
    return value;
}

void push(char* value)  {
    struct s_node *m;
    m=(struct s_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct s_node ));
    m->number= value ;
    m->next=stack;
    stack=m;
}
void display()  {
    struct s_node *temp=stack;
    while(temp!=NULL)   {
        printf("%s\t", temp->number);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

char* pop()  {
    struct s_node *temp ;
    if (stack == NULL) {
        printf("\nSTACK is Empty.");
    } else {
        char* i = stack->number;

        temp = stack;
        stack = stack->next;
        free(temp);  // sadece temp'i serbest bırak, number için ayrı bir free yapmaya gerek yok
        return i;

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to just dump here without helping narrow down where you think the issue is.

Comment: `head1->year = (int) NULL;` Whatever is going on here? An `int` can't be `NULL`, nor can a `char`. Just use `0` for those.

Comment: OT: Please note that [the `fgetc` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. That's very important when comparing the returned value with the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Also note that C doesn't have the concept of "null" values. All variables have a value, and if it's not initialized that value will be *indeterminate*. So doing e.g. `head1->year = (int) NULL;` makes no sense in C. The macro `NULL` is for null *pointers*, not values. If you want to set a variable to zero, use `0`.

Comment: And there are a lot of pointer variables where you just assign one to another for no apparent reason. Cut back on the number of pointer variables, make your code simpler, use functions for handling lists.

Comment: And a general tip for programming: Don't write large parts of code all at once. Instead start with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warning enabled, and treat them as errors. When the code builds cleanly then test the code in many ways. Only when everything works, you continue by adding a new and *very small* piece of code. Do this until the program is finished. That will make it *much* easier to find errors and to debug them when you encounter them.

Comment: Talking about compiler warnings, [your code get a few of them](https://godbolt.org/z/f3q88539v). Some are ***very*** serious and need to be handled. Listen to your compiler, as a beginner it often knows more than you.

Comment: it seems about my 'sortAndPrintByBirth' function. cause till I write it, code works correctly.  do you know what cause to it work when I debug it but not work when I run.

Comment: In the `sortAndPrintByBirth` function, the variable `result` is local. When the function ends, so does the life-time of `result`. The pointer you return will become immediately invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Insufficient allocation**

Member `.next` is a pointer to type `struct n` AKA `node`.  Allocation should be on the size of the referenced data, not the size of the pointer.

```
// head1->next = malloc(sizeof(node*));
head1->next = malloc(sizeof head1->next[0]);
```

**Save time, compiler with all warnings enabled**

[@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586429/i-got-different-outputs-on-run-and-debug-in-c/77586645#comment136780310_77586429)

Comment: it worked, thanks.

Comment: @çağataydişli Be sure to enable all warnings and fix those too.  Also `char fchar;` --> `char fchar;` [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586429/i-got-different-outputs-on-run-and-debug-in-c/77586645#comment136780226_77586429).

Comment: @çağataydişli Tip: run code through an auto-formatter.  Presenting well formatted code helps others think more highly of your work.